# What type of view is Instagram using on the "home" feed?

Tags: android

I thought it was a listview with fragments, but after trying to create one for a bit I am unable to produce results that look or act like that view that you see in apps feeds like Instagram, facebook, heyday, etc. or are they all running HTML5 or something like that?

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and find out for yourself.

Comment: That's actually a great suggestion and a tool that I often forget to use. You should re-post it as an answer.  There's a lot going on in the Instagram view but the UI Automator view tool reveals there IS a ListView in there.

Comment: Agreed, thats a great answer. I did not even know about that tool. Very cool, and it answered my question and probably many more I would have down the road!